# What are the correct autocommand events for various settings?

Tags: autocmd

I have notorious problems finding the right autocommand events for various settings. Usually, my choices seem to be okay, but then there are situations where the settings are reset to default values. In particular, I would like to know the events to use for the following activities:

- setting `formatoptions` to a value of my choice such that any file-type-specific settings are overwritten
- choosing a specific file type for files with a particular file name extension
- setting the syntax highlighting synchronization mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The solution for the first issue depends on whether you want to set particular `formatoptions` values for each filetype, or set certain `formatoptions` values for all filetypes.

  If the former, simply put your `formatoptions` settings in a file named `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` on Unix, or `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\<filetype>.vim` on Windows.

  If the latter, simply put a `FileType` autocommand in your `~/.vimrc` file, e.g.,

  ```
  au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=o
  ```

  See:

  ```
  :help ftplugin-overrule
  ```
- There are a number of ways to do this. The simplest is to put a command like this

  ```
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *.<extension> set filetype=<filetype>
  ```

  in a file named `~/.vim/ftdetect/<filetype>.vim` (on Unix).

  See:

  ```
  :help ftdetect
  ```
- There are a number of ways to do this as well. I usually put the syntax sync command, e.g.,

  ```
  syntax sync fromstart
  ```

  in a file named `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim` (on Unix).

  See:

  ```
  :help mysyntaxfile-add
  ```

  You can find more examples with

  ```
  :helpgrep after/syntax
  ```

Comment: The first suggestion does not work for me. I want `formatoptions` to be `tcqnj` for all file types. I have put the lines `autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions+=tcqnj` and `autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=rowa2vblmMB1` in `~/.vimrc`. When I start Vim with `vim test.markdown`, `formatoptions` becomes `jtcqln`; so there is an additional `l`.

Comment: Regarding the third point, I want to have `syntax sync fromstart` executed for all file types. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion not working for you: if you want to _set_ the `formatoptions` for any or all file types, not just add to or subtract from any `formatoptions` that may have been set by the normal filetype plugin, then use `=`, not `+=` or `-=` in your `setlocal` command. If you want to add additional option values, then putting them all in a row following a `+=` as you have done is fine. _But_, if you want to remove certain option values that have already been set, you should do so one at a time, e.g., `setl fo-=r` `setl fo-=o` `setl fo-=w` and so on.

Comment: Otherwise, Vim will look for the string of option values to the right of the `-=` just as you have written them, and if it doesn't find that exact sequence, won't remove any of them.

Comment: To your wanted to set `syntax sync fromstart` for all file types, I think (I haven't tested it) the solution is to put this autocommand in your ~/.vimrc: `au Syntax * syntax sync fromstart`.

Comment: The `formatoptions` configuration still does not work for me. I want `formatoptions` to be *always* `tcqnj`. Currently, I have the line `autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions=tcqnj` in `.vimrc`. When I run `vim` with no parameters, `formatoptions` is `tcq`. When I create a fresh Markdown file, `formatoptions` is `jtcqln`.

Comment: I have now replaced the previous `autocmd` line by two other lines: `set formatoptions=tcqnj` and `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal formatoptions=tcqnj`. For a few test cases, this worked well. However, it is awkard to have the list of format options twice. Is there a better solution?

Comment: The FileType autocommand event is triggered for those file types that Vim recognizes. To be sure that `formatoptions` is set for those file types that Vim doesn't recognize, and when opening Vim with no file specified, put `set formatoptions=tcqnj` in your `.vimrc`. To set `formatoptions` to the value you want for file types that Vim _does_ recognize, put `au FileType * setlocal formatoptions=tcqnj` in your `.vimrc`. Make sure you put that autocommand _after_ any command that enables filetype plugins, such as `filetype plugin on`. Another way to do this, which avoids ...

Comment: ... listing the `formatoptions` twice is to use this autocommand in your `.vimrc` instead: `au BufWinEnter * setlocal formatoptions=tcqnj`. That will even override any modelines in the file. I don't know why I didn't mention that before.